# OS X: Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, storyboard

This question may have been asked similarly relating to iOS, ***but not OS X***. I've been struggling for three days to simply try and embed an `NSView` or `NSViewController` within an `NSView` using storyboards.

This works fine using a .xib or .nib: (when the next button is pushed it displays either customView1 or customView2 within the Container View.

[image: nib example]

Trying to use a storyboard it does not work. In fact I have no concept or clue on how to connect, embed, call, summons, or beg `customView1` or `customView2` to get itself inside Container View.

[image: storyboard example]

It seems I cannot access anything outside of it's own View Controller!?!

Example of properly working functionality (from .nib):

[image: example]

Comment: So to be clear, you are just trying to add the NSView in customView1 to the root viewController?

Comment: @Siriss, I'm trying to add `NSView customView1` and `customView2` into the `NSView ContainerView` which is in the root `NSViewController`.

Comment: Ahh, the example really helps. For some reason that was not working the first time.

Comment: In iOS you would use embed segues. Are you saying that doesn't work?

Comment: @matt, Well unfortunately there are some differences apparently in the way segues work on iOS vs. OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

You can add two "Container View" objects to your main view controller, as top level objects, and connect them to `NSView` outlets in your controller.  This will automatically create two new view controller scenes, with `Embed` segues from the container view to the child view controller.

[image: Interface Builder]

Your view controller now has references to two inner NSViews and you can manipulate them as you wish.

If you need a reference to the child view controllers, assign a storyboard identifier to each `Embed` segue and implement `-prepareForSegue:sender:`

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(NSStoryboardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqual:@"Embed1"])
    {
        _innerController1 = segue.destinationController;
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqual:@"Embed2"])
    {
        _innerController2 = segue.destinationController;
    }
}
```

Alternatively to segues, you can assign a storyboard identifier to each of your inner view controllers, and instantiate them in code from the storyboard:

```
_innerController1 = [self.storyboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"InnerController1"];
```

You're also free to mix Storyboards and NIBs, so you can design your inner views in a separate NIB and instantiate them in code.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think segues are going to work for this. Thanks anyway.